# AngularJS v1.2.x $digest() infinite loop Directive isolated scope object param

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Simplified version of problem, view web dev console: http://plnkr.co/edit/3wKmWz?p=preview

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:
```

So why does passing an object into a directive with an isolated scope cause an infinite $digest() loop?

```
// controller
// AngularJS 1.2.x infinite digest caused when returning object into directive
$scope.ctrlObjReturnFn = function() {
  return {test:true};
}

// view
<div test-dir breaking-object="ctrlObjReturnFn()"></div

// directive
app.directive('testDir', function() {
  return {
    scope: { breakingObject: '=' },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.html('printed obj: ' + scope.breakingObject.toString());
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is strange, looking at it now. Why would use do it that way, and not just reference the breakingObject *function* inside the isolated scope, rather than the *output* of the function? Bit strange to pass the output as the parameter with an `=`

Comment: Yes, you are right, but this is just the SIMPLEST version used to illustrate the problem. In real life I have multiple controllers/views all using the directive with different flavours of variables being passed in.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're passing in a function as a 2 way binding into the directive, which is not what you should be doing, either pass an object using 2 way binding:

```
scope: { breakingObject: '=' },

<div test-dir breaking-object="ctrlObjReturnFn"></div>

$scope.ctrlObjReturnFn =  {test:true};
```

or a function using 1 way binding:

```
scope: { breakingObject: '&' },

<div test-dir breaking-object="ctrlObjReturnFn()"></div>

$scope.ctrlObjReturnFn = function() {
   return {test:true};
}
```

[See plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/p6FVzVbjpecq19fiX6hY?p=preview).

Comment: OK, @MohammedSepahvand, but why? Yes, we should, but why does the 2-way binding cause it?

Comment: Ah interesting point. I think the 1 way binding would solve my problem. I guess what you're saying is it's broken because I'm passing an object in that is not bound to the scope and so 2 way binding is not possible?